# FindMaximum inside FindRoot error

Tags: equation-solving

I am trying to find the quasi-normal frequencies $\omega$ (i.e. complex frequencies) of the effective potential $Q$ which has to be evaluated at its maximum $x_0$, which itself depends on the frequency. I am trying to use FindRoot and FindMaximum in the following way.

```
M = 1; m = 0; q = 0; QQ = 0;

Q[w_?NumericQ, l_?NumericQ, x_?NumericQ] := 
    w^2 - (1 - (2 M/x) + 
    QQ^2/(x^2)) ((l (l + 1)/(x^2)) + (2 M/(x^3)) - (2 QQ^2/(x^4)) + 
    2 q w (x/(x - M)) + q^2 - m^2);

x0[w_?NumericQ, l_?NumericQ] :=
    x /. Last[FindMaximum[Re[-Q[w, l, x]], {x, 2}]];

D2 = Derivative[0, 0, 2][f][w, l, y] /. 
   f -> (f[#1, #2, InverseFunction[g][#3]] &) /. \!\(\*TagBox[SuperscriptBox["g", RowBox[{"(", RowBox[{"-", "1"}],")"}]],InverseFunction,Editable->False]\)[y] -> x;

g[x_] := Integrate[1/(1 - 2 M/x + QQ^2/(x^2)), x];

n=0;l=1;

QNF = FindRoot[f[w, l, x] - I (n + 0.5) Sqrt[-2 D2] /. 
  f -> Function[{w, l, x}, Q[w, l, x] ] /. x -> x0[w, l], 
  {w, 0.3 - 0.08 I}]
```

The parameters I chose in the first line are just a test case in which the solution can be found by taking a square root. The solution is $w=0.385-0.0883 i$. Upon evaluating QNF however I get Error messages from both FindMaximum and FindRoot:

```
FindRoot::lstol: The line search decreased the step size to within
tolerance specified by AccuracyGoal and PrecisionGoal but was unable 
to find a sufficient decrease in the merit function. You may need more
than MachinePrecision digits of working precision to meet these tolerances.
```

I have played around with AccuracyGoal, WorkingPrecision and MaxIterations to no avail.

Comment: where is `f` defined?

Comment: @glS `f` is just a placeholder to get a general expression for `D2`. It gets replaced by `Q` in the last line. Sorry about the mess at the end of  `D2`. It simply says that $g^{-1}(y)$ gets replaced by $x$. `D2`and `g`are only necessary because i need to differentiate with respect to the tortoise coordinate `g[x]`.

Comment: I don't get the error you mention, I just get an error because the the function in `FindRoot` doesn't evaluate to a number, from the look of it because `Q` doesn't evaluate for non numeric inputs, and there are symbols without values in the argument of `FindRoot` (what is `n` for example?)

Comment: Sorry, I've  just edited in the values for `n`and `l`.